# I am creating a SlidingTabLayout and switching using the tabs is choppy?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, slidingmenu, pagerslidingtabstrip

I created a SlidingTablayout and I keep getting these messages when switching between activites, additionally, its a little choppy when switching between activities

```
01-31 17:45:50.123 4741-4741/com.athena.athena D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1839K, 21% free 26095K/32716K, paused 22ms, total 23ms
01-31 17:45:50.123 4741-4741/com.athena.athena I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 31.361MB for 1872016-byte allocation
01-31 17:45:50.163 4741-4741/com.athena.athena D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2622K, 27% free 25303K/34548K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
01-31 17:45:50.243 4741-4741/com.athena.athena D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1829K, 17% free 26669K/31948K, paused 39ms, total 40ms
```

Answer (score 0):

these messages are for heap which grows as per the memory requirement, if the heap size grows near the app heap limit , the app will get choppy

Comment: avoid unnecesary object creation, check for memory leaks, also how are u using slidingtablayout with activity , i guess u mean Fragment